# Reading and writing to an XML - DTD error

Tags: c#, xml, dtd, xmlreader

I have a program where it reads and writes XML using XMLReader and XMLWriter

```
 XmlWriter writer =
 XmlWriter.Create(fullpath, settings);

 //content...

 writer.Flush();

 writer.Close();
```

and my reader code

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fullpath);

while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch(reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    Console.WriteLine("Element: " + reader.Name);

                    while(reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\tAttribute: [" + reader.Name + "] = '" + 
                        reader.Value + "'");
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.DocumentType: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Document: " + reader.Value); 
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    Console.WriteLine("comment: " + reader.Value);
                    break;

                default: 
                    Console.WriteLine("unknown type, error!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        reader.Close()
```

The writer works fine, but when it gets to XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fullpath);

it prints the unknown type error message twice and crashes with the error

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Xml.XmlException: For security
>   reasons DTD is prohib
>       ited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the
>   ProhibitDtd property
>        on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into
>   XmlReader.Create metho
>       d.
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception
>   e)
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String
>   res, String arg)
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>          at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>          at writefile.Main() in C:\Main\C#June\CH9\CodeFile1.cs:line

I tried adding this before XmlReader.Create(fullpath)

```
XmlReaderSettings settingsread = new XmlReaderSettings();
settingsread.ProhibitDtd = false;
```

I still get the same error, what's the real problem in this program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you would need to change your reader create to reference the settings

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fullpath);
```

should become

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fullpath, settingsread);
```

Comment: you got it, that fixed the problem